# zero inflated binomial data

Tags: regression, model, zero-inflation

I am working with presence/absence data that contains lots of zeros. What is the best method to model this. The only suggestions I can find for zero inflated data refer to count data not binomial/proportion data.

Comment: I don't understand: Doesn't 0 mean "absence" and 1 "presence"? If not, what are the zeros referring to?

Comment: Hi yes that is correct. The data specifically is the presence/absence of a certain decision in a game with which there is many rounds. I am therefore using a mixed model with subject id as the random effects. Maybe I am mistaken in thinking that the high number of zeros is a problem in a glmm with binomial errors?

Comment: I've never heard of zero inflated logistic regression (maybe someone else has?). Of course, if you have *only* zeroes, then you just don't have enough information to fit the model. Does the regression give an error? Something that can happen is [complete separation](http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/mult_pkg/faq/general/complete_separation_logit_models.htm) if the outcome variable separates a predictor variable or a combination of predictor variables completely.

Comment: The difference between a proportion and a count is the total that you scaled by; surely that can't be a problem; just move between unscaled and scaled counts as needed. If your Bernoulli's are zero-inflated, then as suggested there may be no issue. However, there are zero-inflated binomials in R (`VGAM::zibinomial`).

Comment: Yes, I think you are mistaken about what is problematic. Zero inflated logistic doesn't make sense to me, and logistic regression makes no assumptions about the proportion who say 0 or 1

Comment: I am not running into any errors. The reason I thought it may be a problem was because I was getting fixed effect coefficients coming out the model as negative when means from the raw data suggested to me that they should be positive.